# On button click outlook window doesn't open

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have a button on my asp.net page when I click on it it should open an outlook window but i get the following error.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I'm using in my c# page:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;// Version 12.0.0
```

In Web.Config:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
```

It gives an error at this line:

Updated code as per request, I am just trying to open new instance.

```
Application oApp = new Application();
    _MailItem oMailItem = (_MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Just FYI, When I run it on my pc it's working ok, but on the live environment it gives me this error.

**and if the problem with IIS how can I solve it**

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I believe it opened somewhere on server, where your application deployed

Comment: the error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Comment: That's because Outlook not installed on server

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to open email client window on the client where the web browser is running and not on the server machine where IIS is running.

If so, you can simply use [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) links. It will open a outlook window if outlook is installed on the client machine.